# TableAdapter Preview and Fill/Get

Tags: vb.net, tableadapter

So I have a dataset with a tableadapter to a select stored procedure.  If I preview the data, put in parameter values, etc, I am getting the results I expect.  In code, when try to get the data into a data table I am not getting any results, and def not the same results as when I previewed the data.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim ta As New BSDataSetTableAdapters.getBenchLogsTableAdapter
dt = ta.GetData(programid_, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing)
```

Any thoughts or ideas as to what can be happening?

Comment: Post your data retrieval code, you can just put your data directly into the datatable. Unless you need the dataset for other purposes.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Do you mean using sql commands instead of the tableadapter?

Comment: ok, i figured it out.  It is because some of the parameters are integers and setting them to nothing is actually setting them to 0, which screws up the stored procedure bc it is check if they are null and not 0.  Not sure how to address that

Comment: Try DBNull.Value

Comment: Firstly, you need to think about when to use `New` and when not to. The first line of your code creates a new `DataTable` and then the third line throws that away and replaces it with a `DataTable` created by the `GetData` method. Don't use the `New` keyword unless you actually want a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `DataSet` in the designer, select the query in the table adapter, open the Properties window, select the `Parameters` property and click the browse (...) button.  Check the `AllowDBNull` property for each of your parameters.  I expect that you'll find that they are set to `False`.  That means that the parameters of your `GetData` method will be `Integer` and, as you're seeing, `Nothing` will become 0.

Change those properties to `True` and you'll find that the parameters will become type `Integer?`, i.e. `Nullable(Of Integer)`, and so passing `Nothing` actually will mean no value and be converted to `DBNull.Value` under the hood.